# including code from other condition in IF statement without duplicating

Tags: ruby

I need to execute the following code

```
if var == 1
  #some code #1
elsif var == 2
  #some code #1 + some code #2
elsif var == 3
  #some code #1 + some code #2 + some code #3
elsif var == 4
  #some code #1 + some code #2 + some code #3 + some code #4
end
```

How do I can rewrite it in the way without duplicating the code?

Comment: "some code #N" are expressions are they have side-effects?

Comment: What values can `var` take? Is it always an integer? Can it be greater than `5`, etc.?

Comment: Sorry I forget to tell you: var - is always String type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if var > 0
   # code 1
end

if var > 1
   # code 2
end

if var > 2
   # code 3
end
```

No need to run the whole thing inside one large if or case block, unless you get special situations where you only want to run code 3 and code 5 for instance (in which case I'd go for constructing the proc arrays as suggested by tokland)

Comment: +1, with side-effects this is probably the simplest. If the output of code are expressions it would be a different matter.

Comment: Sorry I forget to tell you: var - is always String type.

Comment: If the strings are arbitary, and conditionals would get complex at the top, again you may be best off with tokland's solution. But if this is simply a cascade where each method is associated with a string value and all string values "after" it, you could use an array of strings and matching array of method names, and the .member? method to determine if the next method should be called.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to perform side-effects, an option is to move the code to blocks and execute at will. I'll assume the calls are all homogeneous:

```
proc1 = proc { ... }
proc2 = proc { ... }
proc3 = proc { ... }

case var
when 1
  proc1.call
when 2
  proc1.call
  proc2.call
when 3
  proc1.call
  proc2.call
  proc3.call
end
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
[proc1, proc2, proc3, ....].take(var).each(&:call)
```

Comment: Really like how elegant this is

Answer (score 1):

Use a switch statement instead:

```
case var
when 1
  puts "It's 1"
when 2
  puts "It's 2"
when 3
  puts "It's 3"
when 4
  puts "It's 4"
else
  puts "None of the above"
end
```

If you really want to use if statements, you can use a shorthand:

```
puts 'It's 1' if var == 1
puts 'It's 2' if var == 2
```

Comment: this replicates the if-branches, but does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create different methods and call them.

```
def method1
  return "Do "
end

def method2
  return "you "
end

def method3
  return "believe "
end

def method4
  return "in magic"
end

print "Type in a number between 1-4\nNumber: "
number = gets.chomp.to_i

case number
  when 1
    puts method1
  when 2
    puts method1 + method2
  when 3
    puts method1 + method2 + method3
  when 4
    puts method1 + method2 + method3 + method4
  else
    puts "Something something..."
end
```